# Android/Firebase realtime-database how get only last message?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the firebase Database at the Android Studio. Code java. I use realtime database.
I'm doing a Chat app. I want to show users the last message in their inbox.

I have this database:

```
message: {
       User uıd: {
                Uid of the person he is talking to: {  
                   random key: {
                        -date
                        -from
                        -message
                        -time
                        -type
                       }
                    }
                }
```

I have ref to database als:

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
ChatsRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("message").child(currentUserID);
```

I'm using this to get :

```
  public void messageegetir(){
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Messages> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Messages>()
                        .setQuery(ChatsRef,Messages.class)
                        .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Messages, ChatsViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Messages, ChatsViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChatsViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Messages model) {
                        final String usersIDs = getRef(position).getKey();
                        final String[] retImage = {"default_image"};

                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public ChatsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_list_model,viewGroup,false);
                        return new ChatsViewHolder(view);
                    }
                };

        chatlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
        updateUserStatus("online");
    }
```

my publıc statıc class :

```
public static class ChatsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CircleImageView profileImage ;
        ImageView onlinestatus;
        TextView lastmessage , userName ;

        public ChatsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            profileImage =itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageprofileimageee);
            userName =itemView.findViewById(R.id.messagenameee);
            lastmessage =itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageinfooo);
            onlinestatus =itemView.findViewById(R.id.onlinestatus);
        }
    }
```

Messages class :

```
public class Messages {
    public String data, time, type, message, from  ;

    public Messages(){

    }

    public Messages(String data, String time, String type, String message, String from) {
        this.data = data;
        this.time = time;
        this.type = type;
        this.message = message;
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olwSS.png)

How can I get those data and write them in a textview?

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of it and indicate the exact that you want to get.

Comment: @AlexMamo I replied a little late. I added the image you want

Comment: Please provide a more detailed database screenshot including the inner objects.

Comment: @AlexMamo I added

Comment: Have you tried to add a call to `.child("Uid of the person he is talking to")` to your actual reference?

Comment: @AlexMamo This is what I am trying to do. But I don't know the code to get the uids of every person he talks to

Comment: You need to store each UID in order to create the reference and read the data from that location.

Comment: @AlexMamo is there no way to get uid under user uid?

Answer (score 1):

i suggest that you modify your database structure , denormalize it like it is recommended by firebase docs. see the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure

And you will understand

Comment: suggesting is not answering a question

Answer (score -1):

I did a chat app and the way I did it is that I have two main roots and one is dedicated to getting the last sent message and it updated every time a new message is received and the other root is dedicated to storing a list of all messages between two users so I suggest doing something similar.